# twitter get statuses user_timeline cannot return statuses with non-english characters

Tags: java

I am doing Twitter API calls in Java (using Eclipse as an IDE). While using the Get statuses/usertimeline API call, I noticed it does not seem to return non-English characters properly (e.g. Japanese). It does not return with "???", but it returns squarish boxes instead of the actual characters. Could anybody help to resolve this?

Comment: Generally those boxes mean that the font it's attempting to render in does not have representations for the particular character.

Comment: Now I just noticed that it is storing squarish boxes in MySQL,and I checked on command line that it is supports non-english characters.However,on MySQL workbench it keeps reverting to the default collation.Why is that so?

Comment: In order to figure out exactly what is being stored you're going to have to look at the byte sequence. If a byte sequence is stored that is unrecognized in the character set, it will default to a generic output (such as a square box).